# 14.04 & 16.04 Lenovo 4 GB RAM installed, 3.3 Gb detected

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, lenovo, ram, detect

Fresh installation of Lubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 14.04

Bios sees 4 GB RAM

System detect just 3.3 GB RAM

Device: LENOVO ideapad 110

vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD

cpu family  : 22

model       : 48

model name  : AMD A8-7410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics

stepping    : 1

microcode   : 0x7030105

cpu MHz     : 1300.000

cache size  : 2048 KB

physical id : 0

siblings    : 4

core id     : 0

cpu cores   : 4

apicid      : 0

initial apicid  : 0

fpu     : yes

fpu_exception   : yes

cpuid level : 13

wp      : yes

flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt topoext perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_l2 cpb hw_pstate vmmcall bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold

bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs

bogomips    : 4391.35

TLB size    : 1024 4K pages

clflush size    : 64

cache_alignment : 64

address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual

power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb [12] [13]

Comment: The part you think is missing is actually assigned as "video RAM".

Comment: Thank you.
Can you provide me with more details?
My hardware and software are ok?

Comment: Any discrete graphics has to have part of the system's memory reserved for video rendering. How much varies a lot and my or may not be possible to change it at BIOS/UEFI. The delta seems plausible for a AMD A8-7410 APU. If there are problems, you tell us.

Comment: I was using ubuntu since 2008 (like end-user), an never see this behaviour.  System monitor always shows the total RAM available. If you requiere it, I could print some variables for you, in order to  be sure if everything is allright.

Comment: In 2008 certainly you weren't using a LENOVO ideapad 110 but it doesn't matter anyway. What you used before that reported the full RAM was using a discrete graphics and those have their own memory whereas integrated ones always use the system's RAM.

Comment: I guess I understand you.  Thank you. I was mad because  I thought something was wrong with my new hardware.  For the record, my old machine was a Lenovo G400.  And before, I had a desktop with discrete graphics card.